# Size of Final TestSet

Tags: cross-validation, dataset, train-test-split

is there a rule of thumb of how large the final test set has to be in Machine Learning?

Assumed I have 1.000 images how many images do I ignore and use only in the final run?

My proposal:
Select randomly 150 Images and ignore it until the end.
There are 850 images left I can use.
With 5Fold-CV my test size is 170.
So I have a similarly large test set in the final run as also in the CV.

Is that a desirable ratio?
Are there any papers that address this question?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For testing and optimization, the *absolute* number of tested cases matters since it determines the precision of the measured figures of merit.

In general, one needs to measure this e.g. from a pilot study.
However, in the case of figures of merit that are proportions of tested cases (such as sensitivity, specificity, predictive values, accuracy, ...), one can do the sample size planning beforehand due to the mathematical properties of the binomial distribution.
Here, it's the number of tested cases in the denominator that determines random uncertainty of the performance estimate.  As an example, assume you have 75 test cases truly belonging to class A, and you observe 5 wrong classifications among them. This gives a point estimate for sensitivity of 93 %, a 95 % confidence interval would range from about 87 - 98 %.

See e.g. our paper on sample size planning:
[Beleites, C. and Neugebauer, U. and Bocklitz, T. and Krafft, C. and Popp, J.: Sample size planning for classification models. Anal Chim Acta, 2013, 760, 25-33.

DOI: 10.1016/j.aca.2012.11.007](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aca.2012.11.007)
[accepted manuscript on arXiv: 1211.1323](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.1323)
The idea here is to specify e.g. an acceptable precision or width of the confidence interval or the like and then calculate how many cases one needs to test in order to (likely or surely) meet this criterion.

---

In particular for optimization, you'd want to use proper scoring rules instead of those proportions. Other figures of merit (e.g. Brier's score, which is a proper scoring rule) often have nicer variance properties than the proportions, so somewhat fewer cases may be sufficient. But those nicer figures of merit also cannot do wonders in terms of variance uncertainty (in particular not if the classifier is very black-and-white in its prediction behaviour)